# Google monitor - Dashboard with CPU, Memory and Disk usages with GCE filter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to set up Googlecloud monitor Dashboard for my GCE's. I'm expiriancing some difficulties though when tring to filter.
I have serveral GCE, and some are not running and are as backup, but are still displayed in the Cloud Monitor.

I would like to monitor 3 metrics (for now) : CPU, Mem, Disk usage.
CPU wasnt a problem as i could just filter by  GCE instance name:

[image]

But now if i try to do the same for Memory and Disk usage, I dont have the option to filter as I did using CPU. I tried serveral different approaches like filter by "metadata labels:name", "label", "zone" etc. - all result in a "no data avalible for selected timeframe" (without the filter data is displayed). I feel like I'm missing something trivial:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I filter by Instancename? Do i need to Activate some logger on Google cloud? Thank you verymuch in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Cloud Monitoring agent to gather system and application metrics (disk, CPU, network and process) from VM instances and send them to Monitoring.

[Install the Monitoring Agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/installation#gce-ui-install)

Use the Cloud Logging agent to gather logging metrics from VM instances and send them to Cloud Monitoring.

[Install the Logging Agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation)

Comment: Thank you that was what i was looking for!